# Как обновить php5-fpm (dotdeb)?

Tags: php, debian, php-fpm

Я использую DEBIAN 8.
Поставил связку php5-fpm 5.6.9 (dotdeb). Сейчас актуальная 5.6.12. 
Я смотрел различные гайды и мануалы, но всегда упираюсь во фразу:  **Уже установлена самая новая версия php5-fpm.**

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно можно обновить пакет (установлен через apt-get)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте удалить вашу текущую версию `php`.

```
sudo apt-get remove php5
sudo apt-get purge php5
```

А затем накатить по новой.

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install php5
```